# How to replace login page, after completion of login in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I tried these lines of code,

```
    `Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => object),`
```

But this shows the problems like- I have to close the replaced page twice then  close the application.
(Like, If I replace the login page with dashboard then to close application, I have to press back button and again other times back button)

Comment: In this case, there is another route in the stack that you have not told us about.

Comment: the object comes from the parameter. It can be Dashboard(), ProfileDashboard().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@creativecreatorormaybenot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509751) pointed out there is another route in the stack that you haven't mentioned.

Nevertheless, what you should do is push and remove everything below the stack.

Here is the code

```dart
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => object),
    (r) => false
);
```

Comment: Are you telling about object used there in the code above? That is Class of stateful class like Dashboard(),Profile().

Comment: not it is not releated to object. I mean `pushReplacement` is not working because there is not 1 route in the stack when you call it there are 2 (you might have pushed another route before login)

Comment: I mean push replacement works and i loaded dashboard. After that, to close the app with back button of mobile, I have to close that app twice.

Comment: In need some context there some bug in your code somewhere which is giving you that behaviour. My code should any how work and do what you intend